# Multilingual image names depending on store view

Tags: product-images, store-view

We would like to name the images associated to a product according to the product name. The product name, however, is different depending on the storeview (in our case, language).

Associating an image with a product for any store view also associates the image to all other store views which leaks the language of the storeview that the image was associated with into all other storeviews.

An example:

Product 10001217 is called "magnetic sticker" in one storeview and "Magnetetikett" in another storeview. The product image "10001217.jpg" needs to be associated to the product, however, naming the file "magnetic-sticker.jpg" and "magnetetikett.jpg" for the storeviews helps search engines associate the image contents with the product it represents.

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: Why not use an alt attribute instead of the image name?

Comment: We'd like to use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try uploading the same image with different names in the product. Then, at storeview level, you have the options to assign them as base, main etc, and also to exclude them so they don't end up in "More Views" section in other store views.

Although it will consume more space in server, but you'll get what you need.